# Update Panel duplicating my controls

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net, updatepanel

My code looks like this:

```
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnAddIsotope" EventName="Click" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:gridview id="gwResults" runat="server">
    'all gridview columns go here
    </asp:gridview>

    <asp:ObjectDataSource here>

    <asp:Panel id="pnlAddIso" runat="server">

    <asp:Textbox ID="txtIsoDate" runat="server"   />
    <asp:Button ID="btnAdd"   Text="Add " CssClass="button" runat="server" />

    </asp:Panel>
</ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

when i click the button, its supposed to add an item fromt he txtIsoDate into the database and refresh the gridview.

it adds fine, but when it comes back it creates another copy of my pnlAddIso.

why is this happening? i'm so confused. please help.

if im my button i write pnlAddIso.visible=false, the new duplicate panel does not appear, but the old one does not work anymore....

Answer (score 14):

I had the same problem but did not have any tables, what I did find were unclosed div tags, removed and fixed my problem

Comment: +1 this was my issue as well: a `</span>` followed by five `</div>`s, all of them unmatched, that seemingly appeared out of nowhere (I didn't put them there for sure). They caused my `GridView` to appear twice with the same id and everything.

Comment: Thank you very much..This post save me a bunch of hours on debugging.

Comment: Excellent! I was searching since 2 hrs and there you go. Thank you so much! :)

Comment: excellent. you saved my time a lot. i formatted my page and then found  </div> </div> tags without starting tag. i just removed that and solved my issue. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

I was also experiencing this issue and, as Servy said, the issue seemed to be related to tables. It wasn't consistent on every page.

The first thing I tries was to update the AjaxControlToolkit with NuGet.

In my case, a table encapsulated the update panel.

```
<table>
   <asp:updatepanel .../>
</table>
```

I would look at your control or page, and check if any structure is being interrupted by anb update panel in this manner.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was in tables.

I removed all table tags and now it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

When you push a button, ajax duplicate some controls.

```
ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page).RegisterPostBackControl(yourcontrol)
```